# Add questions about performance to FAQ

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, scope, help-center

Personally, I feel questions about performance are on topic on Code Review. [This topic](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/154/2254) makes me believe most people agree. As an example: [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1330/2254).

Shouldn't **"Performance"** be added to the list of questions you can ask here in the [FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq)?

Perhaps to prevent *"micro benchmarking code golf"* as mentioned by Jeff, a bit more clarification could be added. However, I don't think people will misunderstand it, since above this list of valid topics is mentioned in bold: *"sharing code from projects you are working on"*. This excludes optimizations 'just for fun'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, I think you are right. I just added performance to the list.